# Should I enable Rails force_ssl although nginx handles redirects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, passenger

**Scenario**
I am running Phusion Passenger through nginx.
I have configured nginx to use SSL and reroute all HTTP traffic to HTTPS.
Do I still need to enable the **force_ssl** option in my Rails app?
If so, why and what are the advantages?
If I don't enable it, what security risks do I present?

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen              80; 
    server_name         myapp.com
    rewrite             ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         myapp.com;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/nginx.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/nginx.key;

    root /home/user/rails/app/public;

    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The force_ssl option accomplishes the same thing as the nginx rewrite rule, so you don't need the force_ssl option. force_ssl can give you more granularity, such as making it easier to require SSL in certain subdomains or certain deployment environments. It could also be better if you are more comfortable doing this kind of configuration in Rails rather than in nginx. It will not give you any extra security, however.